# silverstripe: use another "root" - template instead of "Page.ss"

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Is it possible to render another "root" template instead of the `Page.ss` file for some specific pages / controllers? There are already some pages using the `Page.ss` template, but now there will be a new "Intranet" section on the website where the pages should have another "root" template: `IntranetPage.ss`.

`Page.ss` should stay as is and should not be touched at all.

I mainly want different "root" templates because both templates load different JS and CSS files. Also the "container" HTML is quite different.

I was able to create a custom controller which does manually what I need. Something like this:

```
class IntranetPageController extends PageController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->customise([
            'Layout' => $this->renderWith(['Intranet/Layout/IntranetPageLayout'])
        ])->renderWith(['Intranet/IntranetPage']);
    }
}
```

The code is inspired from here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/rendering_templates/

`IntranetPage.ss` is used now as the "root" template. `IntranetPageLayout.ss` is displayed for the `$Layout` placeholder.

That seems to work, however I have many pages which have to be based on `IntranetPage.ss`. It feels strange to write for every new Controller the very same `index` function (with a small adjustment to load another LayoutPage).

I am sure, Silverstripe has some convention to do that automatically :)

What I need is very close to having a individual theme per page, but I am not sure if that is possible...

Comment: Are you not going to leave this `index` function in `IntranetPageController` and then for every new Controller define as `class NewIntranetPageController extends  IntranetPageController`? meaning it's written once and ever page that extends it will use it automatically

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending `PageController`, extend your `IntranetPageController` in new controllers. Whenever `index` is called, it will call your index function from your parent class, in your case `IntranetPageController`.